# how to notify mocha test when Hapi server starts?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, hapi.js

I need to know how to notify the mocha test to start running tests after Hapi server is up and running?

I checked for for express server, where we can emit event of app start and in before hook in mocha listen for event. The same concept is not working with hapi server. "before" hook timeouts while listening for event.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until all your plugins are registered and the server is registered by adding it to the 'start' server events callback.

```
server.events.on('start', () => {
    console.log('Server started');
    // Launch mocha tests here
});
```

Make sure you're properly exporting your server object as well, otherwise it might hang.